# How do I make only one button can be selected at time?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".answer").forEach((answer) => {
    //getting .answer from HTML and adding a click function
    answer.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if (event.target.dataset) {
            document.querySelectorAll(".answer").forEach(e => e.classList.remove('selected'))
            answer.classList.add('selected')
        }
        if (event.target.dataset.correct == "true") {
            correctAnswer++
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.selected{
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
        <h3 id="question"></h3>
        <div class="answers">
            <button type="button" id="answer1" class="answer"></button>
            <button type="button" id="answer2" class="answer"></button>
            <button type="button" id="answer3" class="answer"></button>
            <button type="button" id="answer4" class="answer"></button>
        </div>
```

I have my question and answers in an object, they are shuffled and the answers are put into these buttons, then the selected button get a border. How do I make it where only one button can be selected at a time, and if 2 are selected, the first one is unselected.

Comment: HTML has a native element for this exact purpose: `<input type="radio">`. Consider using `input` element instead and style it as needed. — Refer to [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) for quick reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use a class to apply these styles.

Simply remove the class from every element before adding the class to the current element.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".answer").forEach((answer) => {
    //getting .answer from HTML and adding a click function
    answer.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if (event.target.dataset) {
            document.querySelectorAll(".answer").forEach(e => e.classList.remove('selected'))
            answer.classList.add('selected')
        }
        if (event.target.dataset.correct == "true") {
            correctAnswer++
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.selected{
  border:5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="question"></h3>
        <div class="answers">
            <button type="button" id="answer1" class="answer">1</button>
            <button type="button" id="answer2" class="answer">2</button>
            <button type="button" id="answer3" class="answer">3</button>
            <button type="button" id="answer4" class="answer">4</button>
        </div>
```